# ReactJs jest test fails on vendor modules

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to use Jest in my project like below to test my App class:

```
it('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer
    .create(<Router><App /></Router>)
    .toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

But I get errors from a vendor module and error is like this:

```
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

      at node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.js:222:16
```

I have no idea how to fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why it doesn't work?**

> `renderer.create` renders React components to pure JavaScript objects,
>   without depending on the DOM or a native mobile environment.

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html#testrenderercreate

Is you see `hammerjs/hammer`'s implementation you will find that `addEventListener` is being called on a target DOM Element after finding it in the rendered component. When a DOM environment is not present the target DOM element turns out to be `null` and hence the error.

**How to fix it?**

> If you'd like to assert, and manipulate your rendered components you
>   can use Enzyme or React's TestUtils.

Reference: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-react.html#dom-testing

You can use Enzyme's `mount` for Full DOM Rendering when you have elements that interact with the DOM.
http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html

So this should work:

```
it('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = mount(<Router><App /></Router>);
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```